# Using PowerShell to access Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I have this script working in my code, but, today, it stopped working. Here is what I have:

```
$Excel=new-object -comobject excel.application;
$PathXLSX = "C:\Temp\TEMP.xlsx"
$worksheetXLSX=$Excel.Workbooks.open($PathXLSX);
```

When I run the third line, I get this error:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:1 char:1

```
+ $worksheetXML=$Excel.workBooks.open($PathXML);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0 if you can install modules this will help you greatly

Comment: Agree with @SantiagoSquarzon, however the specific problem is you specified the wrong or mispelled variable to the `.Open()` method. `$PathXML` instead of `..XLSX`  So says the error, though I don't know why the code and the error don't align... Probably a typo somewhere.

Comment: I Did use the powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0, when I started my script. As for the typo, I don't think that is the issue. The code worked fine a few days ago, but today, the same code does not.

Comment: Still waiting for more ideas to try...

Answer (score 1):

That error would be generated if the $Excel object was null. Does it exist?
Try this to see if returns a type:

```
$Excel.GetType()
```

If that is not null then try:

```
 $excel.GetType().fullname
```

That should return: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass

As your codes does not match the error message I'm guessing you have some typos.

```
$worksheetXLSX=$Excel.Workbooks.open($PathXLSX);
$worksheetXML=$Excel.workBooks.open($PathXML);
```

Comment: When I ran the $Excel.GetType() I get this:
$excel.GetType().fullname    I then ran this:$excel.GetType().fullname
 and got this response: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass  As for the typo, I do not see this in my script. It was successfully for a week, before it stopped.

Comment: Mike, can you send a script that will open the workbook then?

Comment: Clifton, you code now looks OK. Here's what I used: $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;
$PathXLSX = "C:\Test\TEMP.xlsx";
$worksheetXLSX=$Excel.Workbooks.open($PathXLSX);$worksheetXLSX.Sheets.count;

Comment: Could the Excel file currently be opened and locked by another user or process?

Comment: No, it is on my computer. Would you mind sending me the script that would work?

Comment: Mike, When I ran your script, I still get this error message: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $worksheetXLSX=$Excel.Workbooks.open($PathXLSX);$worksheetXLSX.Sheets.count; 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $worksheetXLSX=$Excel.Workbooks.open($PathXLSX);$worksheetXLSX.Sheets ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Mike I even did an Uninstall-Module ImportExcel , then rebooted my computer. After that, I reinstalled version 7.10. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I don't see from your code that you are using that module. The "new-object -comobject excel.application" is a generic command that will work on any PowerShell and PC that have Excel installed.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I re-checked my script. The issue is with Microsoft code. Guess I need to open a ticket with their support.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my script working today!

What I did was stop using the Powershell 5.1, that comes with Windows 10, and installed the new version, 7.1. When I call the script from the new version, it runs fine.

Thanks everyone for your feedback!